# How to get chron to convert a vector of Excel serial dates

Tags: r, chron

I am trying to convert an element of a matrix from what were Excel serial dates to a vector of Date objects before using plot().

I can create a vetor and I get the expected result:

```
    library(chron)

# set date origin as defined in Excel

    options(chron.origin = c(month=1, day=1, year=1900))

    test_dates <- c(40917:40920)

    test_dates
    ## [1] 40917 40918 40919 40920

    chron(test_dates, out.format = "m/d/y")

    ## [1] 01/11/12 01/12/12 01/13/12 01/14/12
```

But when I try to use this on my actual vector, it does not work

```
# first 10 vlaues in vector

pivot_pred$date

 ## [1] 40917 40918 40919 40920 40921 40922 40923 40924 40925 40926...

chron(pivot_pred$date, out.format = "m/d/y")

## Error in chron(dates. = floor(dts), times. = tms, format = format, out.format = out.format,  : 
  misspecified chron format(s) length
```

I'm sure this is simple but I have tried many variations and none worked.  Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing pivot_pred (You gave test_dates). Try in base R instead: as.Date(pivot_pred$date, origin = "1900-01-01")

Comment: Maybe you should try `out.format = c(dates = "m/d/y", times = "h:m:s")` as the second argument to `chron()`. If the problem persist then you should provide `dput(pivot_pred)` as pointed out by @ed_sans

Comment: @ed_sans:  Thank you, your method worked.  Also, sorry about the confusion in my post, this was intended to convey the date column:   # first 10 vlaues in vector

pivot_pred$date

 ## [1] 40917 40918 40919 40920 40921 40922 40923 40924 40925 40926...

I should have posted:

 'data.frame': 729 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date    : num  40917 40918 40919 40920 40921 ...
 $ bookings: num  144180 147877 153333 155835 158262 ...

Comment: Sorry for the format issues in my comment; just getting exposed to the lack of formatting....

Comment: @Prem--thank you for your suggestion.  It worked as well; apparently chron was interpreting the series values as datetime.